# IOS Static Table with Custom Cell only draws a random cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, static, application-settings

I am trying to create a "settings" table view for my app. I am trying to mimic it to be the same style as the gneral setting on an Iphone. I have created my own custom cell class by inheriting from UITableCell. I gave it the appropriate IBOulets and i have hooked them up in the storyboard. I also hooked up the switch to my tableViewControler, but for some reason my code is only returning me one empty cell (it being only one cell is not an issue atm for that's all i have in my setting). I triple checked and made sure that I'm using the same cell identifier in my code and in storyboard. Anyone know why I'm getting a blank cell back?

Here is my .h file for my custom cell.

```
@interface NHPSettingsCell : UITableViewCell
@property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UILabel *settingLabel;
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UISwitch *settingSwitch;
@end
```

MY Problem code is here, my .h file for the custom cell:

```
#import "NHPSettingsCell.h"

@implementation NHPSettingsCell
@synthesize  settingLabel, settingSwitch;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

My method for drawing the cell in my custom view controller:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SettingsCell";
    NHPSettingsCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[NHPSettingsCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellStyleDefault;
    }
    cell.settingLabel.text = @"firstSetting";

    //check the if user wants promt of disclaimer each time or not.
    if([prefs boolForKey:@"firstSetting"] == YES){
        cell.settingSwitch.on = YES;
    }else{
        cell.settingSwitch.on = NO;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Now the thing that annoys me is i have successfully managed to implement the cellForRowAtIndexPath method for a dynamic table that uses custom cells. I have also implements the code for a static table using the default cell, but for a static table with custom cells it just doesn't seem to work. Here is the code on how I implemented my custom cells on a dynamic table (note how i didn't have to init the cells but it works).

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"InteractionResultCell";
    NHPResultCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


    // Configure & Fill the cell
    cell.leftLabel.text = [[resultsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] substanceName];
    cell.rightLabel.text = [[resultsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] substanceName2];
    NSString *color = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[resultsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] color]];

    //Change a hex value to a readable 0x number to pass ot hte macro so we can go from a hex color to a RGB system.
    NSScanner *scanner;
    unsigned int tempint=0;    
    scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:color];
    [scanner scanHexInt:&tempint];

    cell.severityButton.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(tempint);


    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two problems:

- If you are using static cells, do not implement any datasource methods in your view controller (numberOfRows, numberOfSections, cellForRow...) as this will override what you have built in the storyboard. The table has the sections, rows and content you give it in the storyboard.
- Cells loaded from the storyboard (either dynamic prototypes, or static cells) are initialised using `initWithCoder:`, not `initWithStyle:`. `awakeFromNib:` is a better place to put your set up code.

Comment: Can you provide some code for how to use initWithCOder? THe same for awakeFromNib. I apologize for having to ask, but this code is due very soon and I'm afraid of breaking functionality atm.

Comment: It's just a standard init method, self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]; if (self) etc. etc. awakeFromNib is a standard method as well. I don't know what sample I can give you?

Answer (score 0):

`dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` works only if a cell has already been created to prevent repeated memory allocations. You cannot reuse a cell without creating it first. The static cells created in the `xib` are the default type. That's why it doesn't work for static table with custom cells. Add the cell creation code after reuse as you've done in your custom view controller's `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method:

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[NHPSettingsCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellStyleDefault;
}
```

**EDIT-** To `init` your custom cell, you'll have to load from `xib`. Add the following class method to your `NHPSettingsCell.m`:

```
+(NHPSettingsCell*) createTextRowWithOwner:(NSObject*)owner{
   NSArray* wired = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NHPSettingsCell" owner:owner options:nil];
   NHPSettingsCell* cell = (NHPSettingsCell*)[wired firstObjectWithClass:[NHPSettingsCell class]];

   return cell;
}
```

and then call it from your custom view controller as:

```
cell = (NHPSettingsCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier]; 
if (Nil == cell) {
     cell = [NHPSettingsCell createTextRowWithOwner:self];
}
```

Comment: You misunderstood my question. My problem is with the code that is in teh first .m file from the top of my post, not the one on the bottom. the one on the bottom works perfectly. THe code block your provided me is already in my code. Or did i misunderstand your comment?

Comment: I changed my post to include "MY Problem code is here" to specifiy which block i'm interested in fixing.